# Cropped image after decoding InputStream received from Servlet

Tags: java, android, http, servlets, bitmap

I am successfully downloading a `png` image from my Servlet, but the corresponding image's InputStream, stored as a Bitmap with `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream, null, null)`, gets unpredictably cropped. My code:

```
public class StaggeredPrenotaTour extends ActionBarActivity implements CallBack{
    Bitmap mBitmap; 
    ImaveView vImageView; 
    //....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //....
        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        // Execute the task
        task.execute(new String[]{URL});
    }
    //....
    public void callbackBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        //vImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    //....

}
```

`GetXMLTask` class:

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    StaggeredPrenotaTour staggeredPrenotaView;

    public GetXMLTask(StaggeredPrenotaTour listView){
        this.staggeredPrenotaView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        staggeredPrenotaView.callbackBitmap(result);
        // setimageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

`Servlet`'s `doGet` method:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream st = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/imgs/cardbackground9.png");

    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    if (st != null) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int nRead;
        while( (nRead=st.read(buf)) != -1 ) {
            out.write(buf, 0, nRead);
        }
        st.close();
    }
    out.close();
}
//....
```

In the following screenshot you can see the resulting cropped image within the `CardView`. The second image shows the first's original size.

Why does it get cut this way? I've been wondering around the web and tried several things but found no solution until now.

[image: this]

Comment: Couple of questions for you: 1) Are all the images that you are downloading supposed to be the same size? 2) What is xml file like for the card layout? 3) Why are you using BitmapFactory.decodeStream( (InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts) when the options are not being used in your case?

Comment: 1) yes 2) this: http://bit.ly/1AifrJm 3) I was using this example: http://bit.ly/1R81UZ0 , but I just removed the Bitmap options and the image is still cropped...

Comment: R the images the same size on the server?

Comment: Yes they are just of the same size